# Stop Auto Logon after failure - Custom Credential Provider Windows

Tags: windows, credential-providers

I've taken up Widows Samples on Credential Providers and have built one using them as a reference. I'm able to log in seamlessly, wither by giving username and password manually. I've set

```
CustomCredential::SetSelected (__out BOOL* pbAutoLogon) {
    *pbAutoLogon = TRUE; // FALSE;
     return S_OK;
}
```

Now, AutoLogon, when the Tile is selected, is happening seamlessly.

As a test case, I changed the password, and as expected the Login fails. After failure, an error message appears and when I click OK ( this is the only option ), the credentials are resubmitted for a retry. How do can we stop this behavior? Which method gets called after the authentication failure?

I've handled `ReportResult()` but that did not help.

Thanks in advance.[image: Error message (nothing to worry about), but after clicking this ok, its goes for retry. I want to stop this.]

[image: Error message (nothing to worry about), but after clicking this ok, its goes for retry. I want to st]

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while - but I believe GetSerialization() is called to return serialized credentials to LogonUI. You need to implement this as well. The credential provider samples I think have working code for KERB_INTERACTIVE_UNLOCK_LOGON.

You can also change *pbAutoLogon conditionally in SetSelected() - I do this in my credential provider depending on certain results.

ReportResult() would be called after GetSerialization returns its result to LogonUI. Inside ReportResult() you could do things like clear the password box (which is done in the samples code.)

If you're not returning serialized credentials in GetSerialization then I think you might get the kind of error you listed in your original post. In the credential samples KerbInteractiveUnlockLogonPack() is called in GetSerialization() and this is what 'logs' the user in effectively.

The error seems specific - 'the user has not been granted the requested logon type' so maybe it has something to do with the rights of the user you're testing with.

If you are using remote desktop, make sure your users are members of the right groups to be able to login (https://support.jumpdesktop.com/hc/en-us/articles/216424183-General-RDP-You-must-be-granted-the-Allow-log-on-through-the-Terminal-or-Remote-Desktop-Services-Right-) or if it is a regular user that it is allowed interactive login.

Also - SetSelected() Gets called when your credential provider is clicked on - I'm not sure if it gets called after every logon attempt or not (my guess is that it doesn't.) In my credential provider I am using a custom logon dialog that I show using SetSelected().

Comment: Thanks for the help @jonathan. What I'm trying to find if the supplied credentials are incorrect or fail to Logon, where do we catch it? 
Conditionally handling *pbAutoLogon is the way forward, but how do we know that it failed? is it only reportResult() method that can tell or anything else?

Comment: Did you have any luck? I've been rewriting my credential provider this week - such an important part of Windows security and I'm disappointed with what little resources Microsoft provides for developers.

Comment: No luck yet. We are writing some workarounds but they don't seem useful. I'll keep posting if we hit anything solid. Please do let us know if you figure out a way.